# Pentaho - Group By step does not return timestamp value

Tags: mysql, database, timestamp, pentaho, kettle

I am using "Group by" step in my transformation and I group a field and pass some other fields as an output in Aggregates. Among those output fields there is a timestamp field that does not return the timestamp value which I pass as input, instead it returns a null value.The type I used for the timestamp field is 'First value'.

Here is my transformation:

[image]

Preview rows in Table input:

[image]

Group by step:

[image]

Preview row in Group by step:

[image]

Can anyone help me fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: provide your example you done far

Comment: @VipinJain added my transformation and preview data images, hope this is enough.

Comment: Is the SQL query from table input ordered by content_id? What if you put a dummy step after the Group by, do you see any rows entering it?

Comment: Do two things:
1. 'select values'-step after table-input: On 'meta-data' in select-values get the two date-values and specify the format for date 'yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss'; get content_id as well and set it to string-format (I don't know if this is necessary ... but give it a try)
2. 'sort by' step before 'group by': sort by 'content_id'.
...hope it works!

Comment: @lukfi,@seb tried both of your methods, but didn't work. Yet gets the null value as result for those fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just disabled the 'Supports the timestamp data type' option in the database connection in Table input step. Then Group by step is returning the timestamp value properly.

Don't know whether it is right, but worked for me.